# Pan and zoomable view container in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a `<div>` as a pan-zoomable view that has some other HTML elements like images, other divs and etc in it. I saw many examples and implements on the internet, but those are using canvas or SVG.

In my case, I don't wanna use canvas to add HTML elements in it, cause the inner elements have some js behaviors that I can't implement them on canvas.

Note that I don't wanna make my inner elements draggable, zoomable or something like that, I just want my entire view to be pan-zoomable. Imagine a 500*500 `<div>` that shows a 1500*1000 `<div>` with some elements in it. Something like google map that has HTML elements inside.[image]

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you plan to use SVG, you can have this functionality using D3.

Comment: @lilezek I tested that. but I have many SVGs in my container and I don't want to every SVG be draggable or zoomable. I want the entire view that contains all the SVGs and other elements come zoomable.

Comment: You can group every SVG in a <g> element with a bit of code, having all the images in a single SVG. Is that an acceptable alternative?

Comment: Use a library like - `https://jqueryui.com/draggable/` or `http://interactjs.io/` I hope I understood the question correctly

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `transform: scale` with some zoom value for this view to zoom. If you want to display 1500x1000 view in 500x500 zoomable view you should use `transform: scale(0.33, 0.5)`. Demo:

```css
.zoomable {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.zoomed {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  transform: scale(0.33, 0.5);
  /* to move transformed elements to top left corner */
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="zoomable">
  <div class="zoomed">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus varius dignissim urna, finibus vulputate mi egestas eu. Etiam non eros lacinia, molestie diam in, facilisis purus. Morbi sed risus sodales, elementum neque quis, volutpat lectus. Nullam
    neque mauris, iaculis quis felis sed, luctus tempus nunc. Maecenas est nulla, tempor sed dictum at, faucibus a sapien. Pellentesque vitae libero urna. Ut porta placerat malesuada. Sed aliquam et risus a laoreet. Nunc vel lacus vel lectus placerat
    pellentesque. Mauris lobortis ante vel mauris tincidunt, ut accumsan magna cursus. Phasellus ante dolor, mollis id congue ut, rhoncus porta augue. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque placerat nibh eget feugiat tempor.
    Nam pellentesque ullamcorper elit eu sodales. Aliquam at mi vel metus condimentum condimentum sed eu tortor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec consequat sapien non dui finibus, sit amet laoreet arcu vehicula. Sed a dui et massa commodo commodo
    ut nec augue. Sed suscipit nibh nec nisl facilisis, nec finibus diam ullamcorper. Mauris bibendum commodo turpis eu fermentum. Sed porta, lectus sit amet pulvinar auctor, ante urna dignissim mauris, hendrerit suscipit magna dui in urna. Quisque convallis
    tellus et semper iaculis. Mauris fringilla velit in magna tempor bibendum. Aenean ultricies at justo vitae congue. Pellentesque a purus sed justo semper bibendum. Nunc ut tortor quis eros laoreet gravida maximus sit amet lacus. Mauris vel consequat
    ipsum, in vehicula eros. Duis enim dolor, convallis sed nunc nec, scelerisque tempus ligula. Nullam consequat velit sit amet risus congue, nec condimentum lacus bibendum. Aliquam ornare justo nec nunc eleifend, tristique condimentum nulla vulputate.
    Donec id orci turpis. Donec porta rutrum massa ac aliquam. In eu ante sed odio dapibus congue. Aliquam tempus nisi nec porta tempus. Aliquam quam augue, commodo at tortor vitae, condimentum eleifend massa. Ut sollicitudin, nunc eget pretium ullamcorper,
    nibh tellus imperdiet enim, at tincidunt nisi metus vel diam. Morbi volutpat velit magna, eu facilisis est luctus volutpat. Maecenas volutpat metus quis elit tristique, non sollicitudin tortor iaculis. Mauris a purus leo. Pellentesque eu mauris sit
    amet est mollis cursus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nam pellentesque cursus mattis. Suspendisse varius elit vitae scelerisque consectetur. Quisque finibus quam quis lacus dignissim, vestibulum
    aliquam erat pulvinar. Ut risus nisi, ultrices eu purus eget, scelerisque tempor ex. Nam pretium placerat orci ut pharetra. Pellentesque sit amet tincidunt orci. Maecenas laoreet porttitor volutpat. Cras vitae mauris mauris. Sed a lacus id felis efficitur
    pellentesque. Nulla facilisi. Integer urna nibh, feugiat commodo lectus at, commodo vehicula arcu. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla mauris lectus, ultricies et elit vel, feugiat ultrices
    sem. Nunc imperdiet sed erat et imperdiet. Donec non tincidunt nisl. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ultricies, massa sit amet congue rhoncus, augue nibh imperdiet eros, vitae ornare risus
    ante id magna. Suspendisse ac leo nulla. Praesent eu ex rhoncus, scelerisque sem sed, porta leo. Sed faucibus, velit placerat lacinia iaculis, turpis libero convallis lacus, eu mattis ante lectus non urna. Fusce semper sodales urna non sodales. Nunc
    ex sapien, ultrices eget dolor sit amet, vestibulum aliquet mi. Aliquam bibendum mollis odio. Phasellus porta commodo est nec placerat. Sed faucibus sapien id enim dignissim, non ullamcorper eros cursus. Integer auctor eu quam ac mollis. Suspendisse
    et nisl lectus. Phasellus purus erat, aliquet et neque in, aliquet posuere sapien. Phasellus eget purus iaculis tortor porta maximus ut non est. Cras ac euismod elit. Vivamus interdum odio sit amet gravida sollicitudin. Cras sed elit vel magna rhoncus
    consectetur ut a ante. Nullam pulvinar convallis nisi quis maximus. Sed ullamcorper neque at luctus efficitur. Donec ligula ex, auctor id magna sed, tempor maximus sapien. Etiam rhoncus, felis sed fringilla pellentesque, justo sapien hendrerit odio,
    eget tincidunt urna magna ac orci. Nam pharetra vitae eros non bibendum. Nulla sit amet ligula quis massa aliquet auctor. Praesent id eros non odio ultricies venenatis a ac metus. Sed ante justo, gravida id ipsum tempor, dignissim dapibus ligula.
    Nulla vulputate cursus fringilla. Ut ultricies ornare quam. Vivamus ac malesuada felis, ac laoreet velit. Curabitur ut nisl pulvinar orci placerat sagittis convallis id elit. Mauris vitae lacus quis metus porta viverra. Nam porttitor neque ipsum,
    et tincidunt nisi interdum a. Suspendisse potenti. Donec lacinia convallis maximus. Suspendisse bibendum nisl ex, nec eleifend magna ornare in. Praesent diam orci, iaculis quis nunc sit amet, mattis rutrum lorem. Maecenas bibendum vel eros non imperdiet.
    Etiam accumsan sem sit amet orci porta, auctor ultricies elit posuere. Curabitur leo mauris, tempus et elementum non, malesuada et velit. Phasellus in tellus vitae diam placerat condimentum vitae quis neque. Maecenas nec eros eget tellus sollicitudin
    fermentum a nec magna. Phasellus sagittis nunc a convallis suscipit. Quisque cursus, dui vitae sollicitudin pulvinar, sem velit rutrum enim, nec dictum lectus dolor nec augue. Nam volutpat metus et semper ultrices. Sed faucibus purus turpis, vel placerat
    arcu posuere in. Mauris a scelerisque ex. Quisque eget pellentesque est. Cras vitae eros sit amet urna interdum ultrices. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam porttitor nibh vitae metus
    varius lobortis. Phasellus vitae vehicula justo. Sed blandit, mi ac scelerisque hendrerit, massa eros ullamcorper orci, ac finibus magna felis nec neque. Proin sollicitudin tristique ante blandit tempus. Proin eget placerat eros. Donec dignissim,
    ligula id hendrerit aliquam, turpis neque pellentesque ligula, nec volutpat dui nisi ac sapien. Nulla rhoncus neque quis sollicitudin venenatis. Nullam sed dapibus nunc. Suspendisse porta cursus scelerisque. In maximus nisl vitae fermentum molestie.
    Cras a diam quis sem scelerisque molestie. Maecenas iaculis aliquam nibh, auctor imperdiet metus fermentum in. Pellentesque ac dui ornare, blandit ipsum nec, placerat ante. Morbi gravida varius ex. Proin efficitur molestie placerat. Nunc suscipit
    arcu eu dui ultricies accumsan. Aliquam quis ex in neque hendrerit porttitor. Donec luctus lorem lorem, quis tempor dolor gravida vel. Nulla eget nisi metus. Curabitur maximus ante arcu, id ultrices arcu pharetra nec. Donec erat arcu, vulputate a
    felis in, aliquet venenatis augue. Nulla sollicitudin in ligula vel ornare. Duis tempor mi et turpis viverra faucibus nec in ante. Cras laoreet mauris at nunc vehicula, eu accumsan ligula eleifend. Mauris vestibulum cursus nunc nec ornare. Morbi nec
    eros orci. Curabitur et dolor gravida elit volutpat pharetra. Nulla dapibus ultrices quam, ut scelerisque odio euismod et. Aliquam consequat nisi at mauris aliquet vehicula. Proin lorem leo, consectetur scelerisque tempus et, sollicitudin nec ipsum.
    Nullam laoreet lectus vitae justo blandit porttitor. Sed et tristique enim. Phasellus nisi mauris, rutrum nec erat nec, scelerisque finibus erat. Sed euismod, diam sed scelerisque aliquet, lectus ante congue dolor, nec commodo nisi massa et turpis.
    Ut vestibulum, mi a faucibus venenatis, mi justo mollis sapien, non feugiat tellus sem id justo. Vivamus consectetur lorem et volutpat volutpat. In dapibus tempor metus id euismod. Nunc eu ligula hendrerit, convallis risus a, varius orci. Mauris sed
    vehicula velit, in rutrum tellus. Etiam venenatis aliquet vulputate. Nunc suscipit viverra consequat. Pellentesque venenatis finibus velit, nec ultricies lorem aliquam vitae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In hac habitasse
    platea dictumst. Nam dictum interdum mattis. Nunc cursus erat ut nisl sollicitudin, a malesuada ipsum rutrum. Maecenas vulputate ligula et ligula tempor accumsan. Nam dictum mi ligula, vel commodo elit rutrum nec. Donec feugiat imperdiet sem sed posuere.
    Nunc convallis egestas lorem vel auctor. Donec et magna at augue rutrum efficitur et non est. In a placerat mi. Nunc in molestie mauris. Quisque efficitur orci a lorem finibus porta. Proin semper nec quam ac posuere. Sed egestas nisl ac nibh egestas,
    ac efficitur mauris sagittis. Nam id tincidunt tortor. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam eget libero porta libero venenatis pharetra sit amet at leo. Ut efficitur, elit et elementum iaculis, mauris ligula sollicitudin
    tellus, in feugiat elit urna in quam. Sed vitae nisi eu nisi congue vehicula. Duis eget tincidunt lorem. Ut sem augue, fringilla quis eros ut, tempor vulputate arcu. Aenean facilisis consequat lectus in tempor. Suspendisse aliquet sagittis mauris
    id efficitur. Nam aliquam purus id lectus viverra luctus. Ut sagittis, leo cursus consequat fringilla, sem nisl interdum ipsum, ut imperdiet sapien ligula eget nisi. Aliquam eget suscipit nisi. Nunc vel lorem sed augue convallis rutrum ac quis arcu.
    Nullam eu mi rhoncus, pretium leo at, luctus turpis. Etiam eget dolor et risus placerat facilisis nec quis tellus. Fusce vestibulum a felis at facilisis. Nulla sit amet est tortor. Suspendisse potenti. Donec aliquam magna vel tincidunt tempus. Quisque
    et nunc massa. Aliquam ultrices, metus eget pretium varius, massa ex vulputate dui, at ornare massa tortor eu urna. Vestibulum semper mi a consequat porta. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc
    pharetra varius mauris. In efficitur, lorem a commodo pharetra, risus lectus pulvinar felis, at pharetra turpis ligula quis sem. Phasellus bibendum, ex sit amet convallis gravida, sapien sapien iaculis dolor, nec iaculis mi elit ut justo. Integer
    est sem, finibus vel ultrices id, ultrices eget leo. Cras luctus sapien sit amet mollis sollicitudin. Nam a turpis ac nisl blandit maximus. Etiam venenatis gravida mi, a fermentum elit congue eget. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit. Proin ullamcorper ex eget turpis ornare porttitor. Proin ullamcorper egestas nunc eget viverra. Proin ornare dui vel egestas vehicula. Aenean sem metus, convallis eget felis vel, rhoncus laoreet elit. Cras ut orci a nisi suscipit consectetur.
    Quisque laoreet, mi ac egestas imperdiet, arcu lectus tempus dui, non semper tellus orci eu massa. Etiam quis enim nec purus tempor dapibus. Integer laoreet dui nec vulputate commodo. Praesent facilisis leo iaculis sollicitudin commodo. In non nibh
    nec quam sollicitudin facilisis. Morbi ut elementum dui. Ut imperdiet semper dui eget hendrerit. Proin hendrerit egestas faucibus. Maecenas faucibus velit vel mauris volutpat, non vehicula dolor suscipit. Integer magna odio, feugiat nec libero eget,
    porta ultrices magna. Sed in tristique turpis. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque ac tortor tellus. Nam placerat nulla non odio convallis ullamcorper. Fusce odio nibh, rutrum a ultricies
    in, venenatis et orci. Pellentesque dictum quis lectus ac congue. Maecenas eleifend quis lorem ullamcorper elementum. Fusce velit leo, fringilla eu congue ut, blandit et est. Fusce sed lacus quis metus maximus molestie. Curabitur euismod turpis in
    ante consequat aliquam a a ante. Mauris lectus nunc, laoreet id libero eu, feugiat vehicula est. Maecenas maximus, ligula ut rutrum mattis, elit nisl vulputate neque, ut condimentum augue est at libero. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis
    parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Mauris faucibus purus eu ante aliquam finibus. Nunc nunc diam, euismod quis sem at, pulvinar porttitor lacus. Phasellus varius metus in mattis pellentesque. Nunc id quam ex.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rem` units for all element's dimensions in your zoomable view. `rem` is `root em`, i.e. `font-size` of `html` tag (i.e. root). And then change `font-size` of `html` tag to zoom.

But don't use this units for the other blocks you don't want to zoom.

Demo:

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.resizable {
  /* 30 * 10px = 300px */
  width: 30rem;
  /* 12 * 10px = 120px */
  height: 12rem;
  /* 0.25 * 10px = 4px */
  border: 0.25rem solid orange;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

img {
  display: block;
  /* 15 * 10px = 150px */
  width: 15rem;
  /* 8 * 10px = 80px */
  height: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="$(`html`).css('font-size', parseInt($(`html`).css('font-size')) - 1)">
-
</button>

<button onclick="$(`html`).css('font-size', parseInt($(`html`).css('font-size')) + 1)">
+
</button>

<div class="resizable">
  This is resizable text and resizable image

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uubYJ.jpg" />
</div>
```

Also you can consider using `em` units if you can cope with calculating proper sizing or you don't have to set different `font-size` values in element hierarchy.

Comment: hmm thanks, your solution is good about zoom. So I should implement events about panning, clicks and etc. Still waiting for some better packages that implement those actions ;)